# If $x^2+ax-3x-(a+2)=0\;,$ Then $ \min\left(\frac{a^2+1}{a^2+2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, optimization

> If $x^2+ax-3x-(a+2)=0\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \min\left(\frac{a^2+1}{a^2+2}\right)$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $x^2+ax-3x-(a+2)=0\Leftrightarrow ax-a = -(x^2-3x-2)$

So we get $$a=\frac{x^2-3x-2}{1-x} = \frac{x^2-2x+1+1-x-4}{1-x} = \left[1-x-\frac{4}{1-x}+1\right]$$

Now $$f(a) = \frac{a^2+1}{a^2+2} = \frac{a^2+2-1}{a^2+2} = 1-\frac{1}{a^2+2}$$

So $$f(x) = 1-\frac{1}{\left[(1-x)-\frac{4}{1-x}+1\right]^2+2}$$

Now put $1-x=t\;,$ Then we get $$f(t) =1- \frac{1}{\left(t-\frac{4}{t}+1\right)^2+2}$$

Now How can I maximize $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\left[(1-x)-\frac{4}{1-x}+1\right]^2+2, }\;,$ Help Required, Thanks

Comment: Is $x$ supposed to be a fixed constant? Or are you simply requiring that the quadratic has a real root?

Comment: @almagest I think that the polynomial is with variable x. On the other hand the polynomial always have a real root, as the determinant $D=(a-3)^2 + (a+2)$ is always greater than 0. Additionally $x=1$, can't be a root, so division by $x-1$ isn't a problem. Anyway I think the OP should consider this important detals in writting his solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$
\frac{a^2+1}{a^2+2}=1-\frac{1}{a^2+2}
$$
Minimizing this is the same as maximizing $1/(a^2+2)$ which, in turn, is the same as minimizing $a^2+2$ or, as well, minimizing $a^2$.

Since
$$
a=-\frac{x^2-3x-2}{x-1}
$$
the minimum value for $a^2$ is obtained when $x^2-3x-2=0$.

Comment: A nice and elegant cascade of minimizations and maximizations ! Good shot.

Answer (score 1):

Minimizing $1 - \frac{1}{(t - \frac 4t +1)^2 + 2}$ is equivalent to minimizing $(t - \frac 4t +1)^2 + 2$. But obviously the minimal value for this is $2$, as the square of a number is always bigger than $0$. To find the value which minimizes it just solve $t- \frac4t + 1 = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Your function will be maximum when the denominator will be minimum.

So, your work will be to calculate $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\left\{(1-x)-\frac{4}{1-x}+1\right\}^2+1\right]=0$$

It will come down to $$2\left\{(1-x)-\frac{4}{1-x}+1\right\}\left\{-1-\frac{4}{(1-x)^2}\right\}=0$$
This will give rise to $2$ cases.

Case-$1$:

$$-1-\frac{4}{(1-x)^2}=0 \Rightarrow x \not \in \mathbb{R}$$

Hence $-1-\frac{4}{(1-x)^2}\not =0$ for any real $x$.

Case-$2$:

$$(1-x)-\frac{4}{1-x}+1=0$$
$$(1-x)^2+(1-x)-4=0$$

So $$1-x=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{1+16}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{17}\pm 1}{2}$$
Or $$x=1-\frac{\sqrt{17}\pm 1}{2}$$

This will give $2$ values of $x$.

Compute $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\left\{(1-x)-\frac{4}{1-x}+1\right\}^2+1\right]$ and check for which value of $x$, the expression comes out to be positive.

That is where the function is minimised, or,  *your actual function* is maximised.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

there is a high-school method.

since $\frac{a^2+1}{a^2+2}$ is an even function, and it's decreasing when $x \lt 0$, and increasing when $x \gt 0$, all we need to do is to find the min value of $\mid a \mid$.

since $x^2 + (a - 3) x - (a - 2) = 0$ has root(s) as real number(s), it follows that
$$
\Delta = (a - 3)^2 + 4 \cdot 1 \cdot (a - 2) \geq 0
$$

so we have $a^2 - 2a + 1 \geq 0$, and the min value of $a$ is $0$

so the min value of $\frac{a^2+1}{a^2+2}$ is $\frac{1}{2}$